# How to create a Hash of Hash in perl?

Tags: perl, hash

I am relatively new to hashes. I have a problem. I have a file in which each entry is of the form

```
187.231.45.47 - - www.xyz.com 200 10567 www.abc.com.
```

The file is a log file and contains around 20000 entries.

I next split the entry on whitespaces and store it in an array, lets say, arr.
so arr[3] is www.xyz.com and arr[6] is www.abc.com

What I want to find out is that for every element in the position of arr[3] how many different arr[6] are present and what is the count of the arr[6] for the corresponding arr[3].

for eg if the log file is

```
187.231.45.47 - - www.xyz.com 200 10567 www.abc.com 
187.231.45.47 - - www.xyz.com 200 10567 www.ab.com 
187.231.45.47 - - www.xyz.com 200 10567 www.ab.com 
187.231.45.47 - - www.xyz.com 200 10567 www.c.com 
187.231.45.47 - - www.x.com 200 10567 www.abc.com
```

then i should get the output 
    for www.xyz.com

```
www.abc.com =1
www.ab.com=2
www.c.com=1
```

for www.x.com

```
www.abc.com=1
```

and so on. I really require help for this. Hope somebody could provide the code for this.

Comment: what else could the - fields be?  in particular, might there be quoted strings that have spaces?

Comment: no sir. those are ust dashes. nothing much to worry i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is doing

```
++$counts{ $fields[3] }{ $fields[6] };
```

for each record of the file.

To generate your output, just use a pair of nested for loops to iterate over the keys of the hashes once your done building them.

```
for my $foo (keys(%counts)) {
   for my $bar (keys(%{ $counts{$foo} })) {
      my $count = $counts{$foo}{$bar};
      ...
   }
}
```

---

Here's the whole thing:

```
my %counts;
while (<>) {
   my @fields = split;
   ++$counts{ $fields[3] }{ $fields[6] };
}

for my $foo (keys(%counts)) {
   print("For $foo,\n");
   for my $bar (keys(%{ $counts{$foo} })) {
      my $count = $counts{$foo}{$bar};
      print("$bar=$count\n");
   }
   print("\n");
}
```

Comment: I will try and implement this out. Thank You.

Comment: @drastogi, Added full program.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create such a HoH is via its structure reference tree, which creates all the nodes for you in the path if they don't exist presently:

```
my $hohStruct;

$hohStruct->{'1'}->{'A'}->{'I'} = 5;
$hohStruct->{'1'}->{'A'}->{'II'} = 4;
$hohStruct->{'1'}->{'B'}->{'I'} = 2;
$hohStruct->{'2'}->{'A'}->{'I'} = 7;
```

That way, when you convert the root `$hohStruct` to hash (`%$hohStruct`), it will have two keys, (1 and 2), `%$hohStruct->{'1'}` will have 2 (A and B) `%$hohStruct->{'1'}->{'A'}` will have 2 (I and II),  `%$hohStruct->{'2'}` will have just one (2), etc.  You can loop and traverse through the structure similarly.  Works identical to a filesystem directory tree.  If your tree depth is fixed by convention and you know the structure, you can write nested for(each) loops to flatten the structure.

So in your case, I would put the 2nd domain name (`www.abc.com`) in the first node below the root, IP in the second level etc.

Comment: `%hohStruct` is an HoHoH. Not sure why, especially since you tell him to use an HoH.

Comment: what do you call a structure with a flexible node depth (like a FS directory) ?  he may have a more complex structure than HoH, to store other fields

Comment: i think the term HoH is applicable regardless of the depth, IOW i don't think we need to reflect the depth of the structure in the plain English naming convention for what we call the thing.

Comment: every HoHoH is a HoH, but the converse isn't true

Comment: i don't intend to be OCD about the naming convention.  to me, one `oH` suffix is sufficient.